# Unable to get the beacon information in my Android app?

Tags: android, ibeacon, beacon

I am new to Beacon and trying to develop proximity Android app using iBeacon.
I have purchased iBeacon from one of the manufacturer in China so I am trying to develop the proximity app where if I found the beacon in the range it show send some notification to the customer. I have tried [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html)
but it is not giving any result .

If anybody could help me how can I use it if I am doing something wrong. I have used [MonitoringActivity](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html)  sample code to test .. but nothing worked .

Please help me .

Here is the code

> Blockquote
>    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
>               new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

```
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        ArrayList<BeaconParser> beaconParsers = new ArrayList<BeaconParser>();
                        beaconParsers.add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(ALTBEACON_LAYOUT));

                        Log.d("Scanned count ====",scanRecord.length+"");


                        String lRawdata="";


                        BLE ble=new BLE();
                        temp_flag=0;
                        //int url_flag=0;



                        String deviceName=device.getName();
                        String deviceAddress=device.getAddress();

                        Log.d("DEVICE NAME",device.toString());
                        Log.d("Address",deviceAddress);



                        int startByte = 2;
                        boolean patternFound = false;
                        while (startByte <= 5)
                        {
                            if (    ((int) scanRecord[startByte + 2] & 0xff) == 0x02 && //Identifies an iBeacon
                                    ((int) scanRecord[startByte + 3] & 0xff) == 0x15)
                            { //Identifies correct data length
                                patternFound = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            startByte++;
                        }
                        if (patternFound)
                        {
                            //Convert to hex String
                            byte[] uuidBytes = new byte[16];
                            System.arraycopy(scanRecord, startByte + 4, uuidBytes, 0, 16);
                            String hexString = bytesToHex(uuidBytes);
                            //UUID detection
                              uuid =  hexString.substring(0,8) + "-" +
                                    hexString.substring(8,12) + "-" +
                                    hexString.substring(12,16) + "-" +
                                    hexString.substring(16,20) + "-" +
                                    hexString.substring(20,32);
                            // major
                              int majorValue = (scanRecord[startByte + 20] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (scanRecord[startByte + 21] & 0xff);
                            // minor
                              int minorValue = (scanRecord[startByte + 22] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (scanRecord[startByte + 23] & 0xff);
                              major = majorValue+"";
                              minor = minorValue+"";
                            Log.i("DATA OF DEVICE","UUID: " +uuid + "nmajor: " +major +"nminor" +minor);
                        }

                        // if(tcz_flag1==1 || tcz_flag2==1 || tcz_flag3==1) {
                        ble.setDeviceName(deviceName);
                        ble.setDeviceAddress(deviceAddress);
                        ble.setRssi(String.valueOf(rssi));
                        ble.setUuid(uuid);
                        ble.setMajor(major);
                        ble.setMinor(minor);


                         //  ble.setNamespaceid(namespaceid);
                        //   ble.setInstanceid(instanceid);


                        int flag = 0;
                        int index = 0;

                        if (bleArrayList.size() > 0) {

                            for (BLE b : bleArrayList) {
                                if (deviceName != "TCZ") {
                                    if (b.getDeviceAddress().equals(ble.getDeviceAddress())) {
                                        flag = 1;
                                        bleArrayList.set(index, ble);

                                    }
                                    index++;

                                }
                            }

                        }


                        if (flag == 0) {

                            bleArrayList.add(ble);

                        }



                        if (bleAdapter == null) {
                            bleAdapter = new BLEAdapter(getApplicationContext(), bleArrayList);
                            listView.setAdapter(bleAdapter);
                        }
                        Comparator<BLE> bleArraylistComparator = new Comparator<BLE>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(BLE lhs, BLE rhs) {

                                String strRssi = lhs.getRssi();
                                String strRssi2 = rhs.getRssi();
                                return strRssi.compareToIgnoreCase(strRssi2);
                            }
                        };

                        Collections.sort(bleArrayList, bleArraylistComparator);
                        bleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   // }

                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Comment: Are you able to see the beacon visible in the demo app given by the manufacturer? 
Do you know your major and minor UUID?

Comment: We will need to see your code if we are to help.  Before you go too far through, make sure your Android device can detect the beacon with an off the shelf app like Locate: 
https ://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. Yes i can see the Beacon visible in the app provided by the Manufacturer ..Major and Minor UUID I am able to find out using the code which I am going to paste in my question

Comment: Could you help now ?